# Flutter StaggeredGridView rearrange crossAxisCount and position of tiles in Grid

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use the `StaggeredGridView` to create a dynamic Grid, were the items don't have a static size but take the size of it's content. To accomplish dynamic sizing I use the `StaggeredTile.fit(1)` and that also works.
But I want to give the ability to rearrange the number of items in one row. For that I set the `crossAxisCount` to a number of 1-3 and that should either place 1, 2, or 3 items in a row. But as you can see in the images below the items don't get rearranged to fit them next to each other but only the size of the tiles changes.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I use a `CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl` to change the value between 1 to 3 and the variable that holds this value is called `segmentedControlGroupValue`. Below you can find the code fot the `SliverStaggeredGrid` and the `CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl`:

```dart
SliverStaggeredGrid.countBuilder(
  mainAxisSpacing: kSmallPadding,
  crossAxisCount: segmentedControlGroupValue ?? 1,
  itemCount: 6,
  staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => Card(
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(kMediumPadding),
      child: Text(
        i.toString(),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

```dart
CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
  groupValue: segmentedControlGroupValue,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
  children: const {
    1: Icon(Icons.menu),
    2: Icon(
      QuaderFont.th_large_1,
      size: 16,
    ),
    3: Icon(Icons.apps)
  },
  onValueChanged: (value) => setState(() {
    segmentedControlGroupValue = value as int?;
  }),
),
```

When I set `crossAxisCount` to 2 and restart the app the grid gets arranged with two items in one row but it is not possible to programmatically change this value while running the app. Or did I just implement it wrong?

Comment: and what does ``HorizontalDocumentCard`` is actually?

Comment: You can ignore the `HorizontalDocumentCard` and `VerticalDocumentCard`. They just either place the title, icon, date and Iconbutton in a Row or Column.  `HorizontalDocumentCard` places them in a Row, `VerticalDocumentCard` in a Column.

Comment: I have just cleaened up the code a bit and replaced the conditional rendering with the code of the `HorizontalDocumentCard`

Comment: I have updated my question with simplified code